# Debugging symbol file for Plugin.Audiorecorder.dll is not valid and was ignored

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

When I try to archive my xamarin forms app for publishing it gives the following error: Debugging symbol file for Plugin.Audiorecorder.dll is not valid and was ignored.

When I try to run the app in a simulator everything works fine.

How can I fix this?

I have tried to clean the solution and rebuild it.
I have deleted the bin and the obj folder.
I have changed the debugging options to portable.
But nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed other Nuget packages in your app. When archiving it, it'll cause conflicts between assemblies. You should try to resolve it by eliminating those conflicts.

If it still doesn't work, I suggest you directly [report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report) it to VS Product Team, from `VS > Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem`.